# Complex notation convention for time variation

Tags: waves, conventions, complex-numbers

In describing plane wave EM variation, some textbooks use the complex notation $\exp(i\omega t)$, while others use $\exp(-i\omega t)$.

Is there a motivation for chosing one or the other convention, such as possibly consistency with some other issue?